# jQuery datepicker() Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Can anyone please help me I am struggling with this problem for the past few day. Actually I included all the necessary plugins' but still the

`$('#datepicker').datepicker()` function is not defined ERROR.

I included the same plugins' in the other jsp of my projects there the datepicker works perfectly.

This is what I tried.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
```

It throws the exception on page load itself.
Thanks.

Comment: I tried the samething in jsfiddle It works there too http://jsfiddle.net/johnduraibritto/32v9fhx9/ but not in that particular jsp file

Comment: Can you list all the included js ?

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready(function()` as it is in jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi @AmitGarg i have included these files            http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js

Comment: HI I included only jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-ui.js only.

Comment: Hi All thanks for your help I found the problem and fixed it now it work's fine. The problem was i included the jquery-1.10.2.js twice i made it once now it's fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please double check the js files you include if you include the same js file twice are different version of same file twice, It will conflict. Have patient to go through to entire jsp or html file to check the js files.

Comment: You just save my life. Been 1 hour struggling with this error.  I followed your advice and saw a 2nd inclusion in my footer.  Zillion Thx!

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue and solved it using `$.noConflict();`:

Instead of `$( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();`, I used:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent lots of time on this. Found the issue to datepicker function not found and or not working in Chrome. Using VS2015... Just about everything is dependant on JQuery so it must be at the very top. Use the following references or latest:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

1. Open _layout.cshtml
2. Paste at the top of each Environment section. Check the body as well. (I was missing the body)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress, make sure you replace "$" with "jQuery" in the .js files.

Answer (score 0):

check the reference what you have added and the reference what you have in the scripts folder. 
example:
if you have referred [jquery-ui.min.js] in your .cshtml but you have [jquery-ui.min-1.13.0.js] in your scripts folder then this error will occurs