# How to Fix datepicker Error using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am getting below error...

***Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function***

Here is my Code:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
function date_chng(id) { 
    $('#' + id).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            if (this.id == id) {
                var dateMin = $('#' + id).datepicker("getDate");
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
<input required  type="text" id="ifs_dd_1" onMouseOver="date_chng(this.id);"  name="ifs_dd1"/>
```

Comment: Use the datepicker plugin file after jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You load Jquery-ui before Jquery itself like this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

You get error in the ui file because it is hasn't loaded Jquery yet. Simply switch it up:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Working example with your code, you don't load Jquery correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lopj0y93/

Comment: Show me the code where you inject jquery file, because that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I check all my included popup files...& fix it...It's because of including two times Jquery mins files.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/512301/jQueryplusdatepickerplusissue-aplusUncaughtplusTy

[jQuery datepicker() Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248363/jquery-datepicker-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function)